# py2exe while using anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe

Using anaconda 3.5/jupyter/spyder.
I have installed Py2exe 0.9.2.2 which supports Python 3.3 and above.
I am interested in creating an executable file from python script.
The code `py -3.4 -m py2exe.build_exe myscript.py` does not work in jupyter notebook and anaconda prompt.
i see **python.exe** file located in the folder:

> C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: "does not work" - what's the error message?

Comment: `@Jeronimo` thanks.
Current working directory is C:\Users\me\AnacondaProjects\py2exe
`In [8]: print('hello world!')`
hello world!
`In [9]: py -3.4 -m py2exe.build_exe hello.py`
**error message**
File "<ipython-input-9-a361fa544b02>", line 1
    py -3.4 -m py2exe.build_exe hello.py
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

'In [10]: build_exe hello.py'

**error message**  
File "<ipython-input-10-e4bdea309ba3>", line 1
    build_exe hello.py
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Wherever you took that from, but it looks like a command line. Or maybe there's an IPython magic command "%py" that I dont know of. Anyways, try opening a command line in your Anaconda folder, and do `python.exe -m py2exe.build_exe C:/full/path/to/myscript.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jeronimo answer worked right.

> Wherever you took that from, but it looks like a command line. Or maybe there's an IPython magic command "%py" that I dont know of. Anyways, try opening a command line in your Anaconda folder, and do `python.exe -m py2exe.build_exe C:/full/path/to/myscript.py`.